# let $y^2=4ax$ be a parabola and $x^2+y^2 +2bx=0$ be a circle. parabola and circle touch each other externally

Tags: circles, conic-sections

the parabola and circle touch each other externally, the focus of parabola and centre of circle lie on $x$ axis, then $a$ and $b$ must be both greater than $0$ or both must be less than $0$ (if they have same signs then only they can touch externally because centre of circle is $(-b,0)$.

but when i solve the two curves and equate discriminant to $0$ then signs of $a$ and $b$ come out be opposite . why is that?

Comment: Where is the parameter a  in the equations?

Comment: edited thanks .

Comment: By equating a discriminant to zero you are solving a quadratic equation, that has two solutions. Maybe you simply took the solution with the wrong sign?

Comment: As per your calculations, On equating discriminant to zero, you will be getting   $b=-2a$  which is the condition of touching (internally or externally) rather than intersecting each other.

Comment: b=-2a is the condition when they touch internally. from where do i bring the condition when they touch externally.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equations $$y^2=4ax\tag 1$$ $$x^2+y^2 +2bx=0\tag 2$$ Replace $y^2$ from $(1)$ into $(2)$. This gives $$x^2+(4a+2b)x=0 \tag 3$$ the solution of which being  $$x_1=0 \qquad, \qquad x_2=-2(2a+b)$$ Using thesese values in $(1)$, we then have $$y_1=0 \qquad, \qquad y_{2,3}=\pm 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{-a (2 a+b)}$$

Comment: i need to prove that a and b are either both less than 0 or greater that 0, i dont need to find solutions

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Any point on $y^2=x$ is $(at^2,2at)$

So, the equation of the tangent $$y(2at)=4a\cdot\dfrac{x+at^2}2\iff x-yt+at^2=0$$

It will also be  a tangent of  $$(x+b)^2+y^2=b^2$$

if $$|b|=\dfrac{-b+0(-t)+at^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$

$$\iff b^2(1+t^2)=(at^2-b)^2$$

If $t\ne0,$
$$\iff\dfrac{b(b+2a)}{a^2}=t^2>0$$